# How can "Save All" button press be handled in Visual Studio Extensibility?

Tags: visual-studio, events, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I need to have some action performed when "Save All" button is pressed. If I subscribe to `DocumentSaved` event that event is invoked once for each unsaved document and this is kind of a problem because I'd rather have the action invoked for the documents collection instead of for each document separately.

Is it possible to handle "Save All" as a single action instead of handling multiple `DocumentSaved` events?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: The action needs to be done for the bunch of documents as a whole, that's why.

Comment: But what happens if I save a bunch of documents one at a time. Then what should you do?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Let's pretend this should be handled as separate saves.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the command execution events with the following code:

```
events = dte.Events;
commandEvents = events.get_CommandEvents(null, 0);
commandEvents.AfterExecute += OnAfterExecute;
```

In your OnAfterExecute handler you can check if it is the File.SaveAll command: [VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.SaveSolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsstd97cmdid.aspx).