# Extending Visual Studio (add in)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a add in for visual studio, what I would like to do is run my add in after another command has been run.

For instance my addin is used to record modifications to files for an internal tool that shows what needs to be copied across from the dev server to production server, in case a dev is ill or on holiday etc.

So the timeline would be

(user clicks checkin) --> (my add in runs) --> (success / error message)

I have googled and looked on stackoverflow but just cant seem to find anything that notes how to do this.

Edit:

I cannot use macros due to the way each dev station is personalised

Comment: Maybe it would be smarter to do this as a hook in your source code repository? What happens if someone checks in code with a client other than Visual Studio?

Comment: We are a Visual Studio only house and you cannot access source control unless you are using Visual Studio : Fair point though and if it was not part of a larger system this would probably make sense

Comment: You seem to be rebuilding something that most source control systems already bring. Depending on your source control system (as a VS user, maybe TFS?) you may already have that capacity without the need for an addon.

Comment: We are using Source Gear Vault and although it shows what files have been modified in the admin interface and the desktop client. these are locked down to select users. it also feeds into a larger automated application that we are building for internal use due to client requirments. it is not a killer as I currently have a working solution but would prefer to maybe make it a bit more seamless

Comment: You can subscribe to CommandEvents, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21329823/84507

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thanks that is exactly what I needed, if you turn your comment into an answer I will mark it as such