# Save all changes programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am making a VS Extension and as part of the application,I would like to save all changes that the user made in the editor and then build the Project. How can I do that programmatically?

**EDIT**: My question is **VERY** different from the question being marked as a duplicate question. The other question has to do with handling an event that is fired when the user clicks "Save All" while my question is asking how to SaveAll() programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can "Save All" button press be handled in Visual Studio Extensibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303140/how-can-save-all-button-press-be-handled-in-visual-studio-extensibility)

Comment: Do you expect this to happen on each keystroke?  Once every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

dte.Documents.SaveAll() does the trick.